# Can anyone explain me how to install this file?

Tags: repository, github

I was reading a Linux magazine PDF ( Linux magazine special edition [US] , July 2021)
[ 101 cool LINUX hacks]
and at hack 86, (as shown in the image below):

[image: a screenshot of the page]

( I'm not using Windows 7 , it's just a theme)
it said about a git manager, but I just couldn't install it properly (I have installed github) , I wonder if anyone could describe me how install it.

As you may have noticed, I'm a newbie to git repositories.
[Solved]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? You do not need the screen shot just the name of the app. Did you do any research there many site that talk about this app.

Comment: I suggest you read the install documentation at https://github.com/rgburke/grv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instructions are there on [the Github site](https://github.com/rgburke/grv), but they are quite concise and intended for experienced users, so I'll elaborate a bit. Look under the "Linux" header. Three commands are given:

1. A `wget` command that allows you to download the program. This command will store the program in the current directory, so you may want to create a directory just for this purpose, let's say `/home/[username]/grv`, and `cd` into this directory. This program doesn't need to be installed, and apparently it doesn't need any additional packages or libraries.
2. A `chmod` command. Downloaded files are never executable straightaway, for security reasons. You must set the executable bit yourself. This command does that.
3. The command to actually launch the `grv` program. The path to the git repro to be viewed is a parameter. You may want to create a desktop shortcut for this program. Use `/home/[username]/grv/grv` as the executable path.

That is all.

Comment: Thak you so much , it is solved now , again thank you for your yime.

Comment: If my post answers your question, please mark it as such by ticking the check mark next to it. Thank you.